# Mutator funciona no tinker e não funciona na view do blade no Laravel 7.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, collection

Galera, eu consegui executar um erro meio bizarro aqui no Laravel.

Eu defini um método *accessor* em um modelo, testei no *tinker* e tudo certo, a sintaxe tá certa e funciona OK.

Porém, quando eu tento acessar esse mesmo atributo em uma *blade view*, eu só recebo erro atrás de erro, não consigo obter o resultado esperado!

E o mais curioso é que na blade, se eu executo um `dd()` no atributo, a informação que eu quero está lá!

**Holder.php**

```php
public function getLastEarningAttribute()
{
    return $this->uuids->last()->earnings->last()->value;
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```html
@foreach($holders as $holder)
<td class="text-center">{{ $holder->last_earning }}</td>
@endforeach
```

A variável `$holders` está sendo passada normalmente pelo Controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $holders = Holder::all();
    return view("dashboard.holders.home", compact("holders"));
}
```

E mesmo assim, eu não consigo sair do erro:

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property 'earnings' of non-object (View: ***\resources\views\dashboard\holders\home.blade.php)
```

E executando o `dd($holder->last_earning)` no **home.blade.php** dentro do `@foreach($holders as $holder)`, o resultado que eu quero é apresentado normalmente: `27.04`. Assim como quando eu executo o mesmo atributo no *tinker*, o resultado esperado também vem.

```bsh
>>> Holder::find(1)->last_earning
[!] Aliasing 'Holder' to 'App\Holder' for this Tinker session.
=> 27.04
```

Os relacionamentos dentro de `Uuid::class` e `Earning::class` estão todos corretos e funcionando normalmente em suas respectivas views.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que em um dos holders, este trecho  `$this->uuids->last()` retorna null.

Seu `dd()` provavelmente funciona porque não deve ser o caso do primeiro registro; entretanto, algum deles deve retornar `null` nessa parte do código que mencionei acima e como está num foreach, quando passar por este registro vai acontecer o erro que está acontecendo.

Acho que a solução seria validar no próprio mutator se last() retorna null, seja com if ou se estiver usando o php 8, você pode usar o [null safe operator](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/null-safe-operator#:%7E:text=Null%2Dsafe%20operator%20is%20a,null%20%2C%20without%20causing%20any%20errors.).

Comment: Cara, falta de sono adequado, fiquei até 2h tentando resolver isso, tinha esquecido que uuids podia ser nulo. Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema!